# QuickSort critique

Tags: python, algorithm, quick-sort

This is my first attempt at Quick Sort and am looking for some helpful criticisms on how I can make my code better. Thank you

```
def manSort(self, unSorted):
    if len(unSorted) <= 1:
        return unSorted
    else:
        greater = []
        less = []
        pivots = unSorted[len(unSorted)/2]
        pivotPlace = [pivots]
        for i in range(len(unSorted)):
            if unSorted[i] < pivots:
                less.append(unSorted[i])
            elif unSorted[i] > pivots:
                greater.append(unSorted[i])
            elif i == len(unSorted)/2:
                pass
            else:
                pivotPlace.append(unSorted[i])

        return self.manSort(less) + pivotPlace + self.manSort(greater)
```

Comment: What about the function that has 2 nested `for` loops that iterate over each element and swaps the lowest, returns the same list but sorted?
It's not what the task requires but, is it faster?

Comment: There are [alternative quick-sort implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) that use less space. It also possible that they might be faster, but that would depend on the implementation of the python interpreter, so you'd have to measure it to be sure. I don't know that any of them have nested for loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks pretty good. There are a few small things that can use improvement. For clarity, I'd avoid the name `pivotPlace` in favor of `equal`, since that's what the function does, it places the values equal to the pivot there.

As Janne mentioned, the `for` loop can be replaced by one that loops over the items in the unsorted list.

A floor division instead of regular division ensures that this will also work for Python 3.

Lastly, the `else` can be removed entirely (control never flows there if the initial condition is true), pulling code further to the baseline.

```
def manSort(unsorted):
    if len(unsorted) <= 1:
        return unsorted

    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    pivot = unsorted[len(unsorted) // 2]
    for item in unsorted:
        if item < pivot:
            less.append(item)
        elif item > pivot:
            greater.append(item)
        else:
            equal.append(item)

    return manSort(less) + equal + manSort(greater)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not following the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide, which is the *official* style for python code. to fix this:

- Identifiers should be `lower_case_with_underscore`
- functions should be `lower_case_with_underscore`
- classes should be `FullCamelCase`

You are iterating over the *indeces* of the list, this is not pythonic at all. Use a plain `for` instead:

```
for element in sequence:
     # work with element
```

If you *need* also the index, then use the `enumerate` built-in:

```
for index, element in enumerate(sequence):
    # work with element and its index
```

Your method is actually a *function*. It never uses `self` except when performing the recursive calls, hence you should consider putting this outside the class, or make this method a `staticmethod`.

Some identifiers have strange names (e.g. `pivot_place`).

Lastly, your code is suboptimal. It uses `O(nlog(n))` space instead of `O(log(n))`. The usual implementations of quicksort use a `partition` algorithm that moves the elements *in-place*, without creating temporary `lesser`, `greater` lists. With such a function the whole implementation of quicksort becomes:

```
def quicksort(sequence, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(sequence)
    if end - start > 1:
        q = partition(sequence, start, end)
        quicksort(sequence, start, q)
        quicksort(sequence, q+1, end)
```

Where the `partition` can be something like:

```
def partition(sequence, start, end):
    pivot = sequence[start]
    sequence[start], sequence[end-1] = sequence[end-1], pivot
    # i: index of the last "lesser than" number.
    i = start - 1
    # j: index to scan the array
    for j in range(start, end-1):
        element = sequence[j]
        if element <= pivot:
            i += 1
            sequence[i], sequence[j] = sequence[j], sequence[i]
    # move pivot in the correct place
    i += 1
    sequence[i], sequence[end-1] = sequence[end-1], sequence[i]
    return i
```

In this code I did iterate over the indices because the iteration starts at some index `start`. In your case you always iterated over the whole sequence.

Note that this implementation uses `O(log(n))` memory in the average case, `O(n)` in the worst case, but the worst-case may be a problem since it's when the input is ordered.

To increase performance you should randomize the `partition` function. You simply have to change the initial lines:

```
import random

def partition(sequence, start, end):
    # use a random element instead of the first element.
    pivot_index = random.randint(start, end-1)
    pivot = sequence[pivot_index]
    sequence[pivot_index], sequence[end-1] = sequence[end-1], pivot
    # same as before.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an unnecessary complication: you put `pivots` in `pivotPlace` before the loop, and then do extra work to skip it in the loop.

You could also loop over `unSorted` directly instead of looping with an index.

```
pivotPlace = []
for item in unSorted:
    if item < pivots:
        less.append(item)
    elif item > pivots:
        greater.append(item)
    else:
        pivotPlace.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list-comprehension or the filter function. What you are effectively doing is an inline-filter.

#### List comprehension

```
def quicksort(xs):
  if xs == []: return []
  pivot = xs[0]
  lesser = [x for x in xs[1:] if x < pivot]
  greater = [x for x in xs[1:] if x >= pivot]
  return quicksort(lesser) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)
```

#### Filter

```
def quicksort(xs):
  if xs == []: return []
  pivot = xs[0]
  lesser = list(filter(lambda x: x < pivot, xs))
  greater = list(filter(lambda x: x >= pivot, xs))
  return quicksort(lesser) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)
```